# Because of overflow on a list, a dropdown menu can't pop on the left of this list (minus margin-left)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/od4vjhbc/6/

Basically, when overflow is set on `#contact-list`, the dropdown menu (when clicking on a contact in the list) is not completely shown, as it gets cut.

Remove / comment the overflow on #contact-list, then the popup will be fully shown.

How I can make it work well (menu to be fully shown when clicking the contact) even if overflow is set? (Overflow required if there are a lot of contacts in the list).

What kind of structural change to the HTML should I do, if required?

Comment: Why are using a style that is designed to do something that you specifically want to prevent?

Comment: Only adding `overflow` breaks it -- which is something I add whenever I need a scroll bar in a list. Never had this problem before because I've never had drop down menus that needed to appear beside the scrolled content.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't have it both ways. If you want to be able to scroll your list, your popup will be hidden as long as it is a descendant of `#contact-list`. Are you sure you don't mean to change the `overflow` for `.contact-dropdown`. Also your HTML is invalid.

Comment: The overflow needs to be for the contact list, as thats where someone can have many contacts and a scroll would be needed. What kind of structural change do I need to do? My HTML/CSS is not my strength and it's completely blocking me from going forward with the rest of my app still

Comment: I don't understand. the answer is to remove `overflow-y: auto;` why do you need to keep overflow set to auto?

Comment: So a scroll bar appears if there are many contacts in the list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17432665/1305911 <-> http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/od4vjhbc/7/

Answer (score 0):

apply your overflow to the .name div instead of the #contact-list

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mn01ouat/

```
 #contact-list {
  width: 150px;
  float:right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 300px;
  /*overflow-y: auto;*/
}

#contact-list .name{
  width: 150px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```